# Detect Foot and Place 3D model Boots in ARKit

Tags: object-detection, scenekit, arkit, coreml, apple-vision

I want to detect foot using Scenekit(ARKit) and place 3D shoes same like body detect and place shirts onto it.
Is there any help ? how can i do that ?
ARkit ? Vision ? or CoreML

What will be the sequence of the work ?

Comment: Did you found any solution for this? If yes can you pls update it..

Comment: Trying my best, solution exists but there is accuracy issue, Just follow this sequence 

ARkit -> Vision -> then CoreML to train model.

Similarly when you detect the foot using CoreML you have to reverse back like this

CoreML -> Vision -> ARKit

Comment: Any sample code or tutorial available for this..

Comment: Any update on this?